# Math behind Portal Reloaded - Chamber 07

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-equations

So, I was playing this game called Portal Reloaded, which is basically Portal but with time travel added into the mix.

I found it quite a conundrum to clear Chamber 07, and decided I should try to improve my understanding of solving it before I proceed forward. I was able to solve it, but I'm pretty sure the levels ahead are only going to get more tough as one would expect from a video game of that nature.

Looking for a way to represent my steps mathematically. Please explain everything like I'm ten. I have drawn a flowchart of the steps I hade to take to clear the level. I have been told to look into finite state machines and state transition diagrams regarding to understand the same. Can this be represented as a system of equations?

Step by Step Flowchart
[image: Step by Step Flowchart]

Legend
[image: Legend]

A, B and 07 are just names of platforms.

T1, T2 and T3 are time portals.

Arrows indicate player movement.

**UPDATE**

Ok, so I broke down the steps into statements

The colored strips on the left hand side indicate when the actions are performed (Present or Future)

The strips on the right hand side indicate the Spiral from the flowchart that we are currently following (the gif is made up of four stages or spirals)

The tables represent the status of both the portals across both the timelines and the physical space connected by them.

[image]

Comment: This is an interesting question. Expressing something in equations entails thinking very carefully and precisely about how exactly to describe it so I think you should edit in a clear description of the rules of the game's mechanics. A video of the puzzle would probably also be helpful. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UEad76JCvEE